# background bashscript in if conditional

Tags: bash

I'm calling a bash script in if conditionals

```
for i in "${array[@]}"; do 
    if ! ./script2.sh $i ; then break ; fi
done
```

it works fine, but if I call the script as a background process with the following variations, I would get syntax error:

```
for i in "${array[@]}"; do 
    if ! ./script2.sh $i & ; then break ; fi
done
```

```
for i in "${array[@]}"; do 
    if [ ! ./script2.sh $i & ]; then break ; fi
done
```

what's the right way to do it?

Comment: You are already pushing the script to bg job, So now you wont have any control on this. Use some echo statements in your script with the exit status then you can validate whether the job is done or not properly.

Comment: `& ;` doesn't work because `;` and `&` are both command terminators.  In the second code, you could drop the `;` and it would 'work' (no syntax error) but it probably wouldn't do what you want.  You need to consider what you're after.  You run jobs in the background when you don't care about their exit status and you don't want to wait for them to complete.  The third variation is confused. The `[` command is a command, not a syntactic construct. Nominally, the code runs `[ ! ./script.sh $i` in the background, and then tries to run `]`. The first fails because `[` expects `]` as the last arg.

Answer (score 0):

You could save its output in a temporary variable and check it instead.

```
for i in "${array[@]}"; do 
    tmp="$(./script2.sh "$i")"
    if [ ! "$tmp" ]; then break ; fi
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Its not clear why you want to background it, but this should work for you:

```
for i in "${array[@]}"; do 
 ((! $(./script2.sh "$i" &))) && break; 
done
```